# Ember select default value

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

I am unable to select a default value in an ember select. Here is what the code looks like

Models:

```
rfwa.Field = DS.Model.extend({
    Name: DS.attr('string'),
    FieldTypeId: DS.attr('number'),
    FieldType: DS.belongsTo('fieldType'),

});

rfwa.FieldType = DS.Model.extend({
    Name: DS.attr('string')
});
```

Route:

```
rfwa.FieldRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
   model: function (params) {
       var route = this;
       return Ember.RSVP.hash({
            field: route.store.find('field', params.field_id),
            fieldTypes: route.store.find('fieldType')
       });
    },
    setupController: function (controller, model) {
        controller.set('fieldTypes', model.fieldTypes);
        controller.set('model', model.field);
    }
});
```

Template:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="Field">
   {{input value=model.Name class="form-control" id="Name"}}
   {{view "select" content=fieldTypes optionValuePath="content.id" optionLabelPath="content.Name" value=model.FieldTypeId classNames="form-dropdown"}}
</script>
```

I have fiddled with a lot of possibilities using selection and value in the view. Creating functions that returns a fieldType for selection. So far, nothing has worked. there has to be something I am doing wrong.

I am using Ember 1.12.1 with Ember-data 1.0.0-beta18.

Currently with what I have pasted, it sets my model.FieldTypeId to undefined when the page loads.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why it didn't work is because the id from DS.Model is a string while my FieldTypeId was a number. I changed my model to

```
FieldTypeId: DS.attr('string')
```

And this solved all my problems.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you had a controller defined but if you are setting properties on it you should define one with those properties at least.  I set up a jsbin to show what you can do as far as setting the default selection and binding it:

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/qijudidade/1/edit?html,js,output

Comment: The jsbin provided does exactly what I need. However, reproducing this code in my app doesn't work! I'm using a RestAdapter though. I put selection=selectedFieldType and the selectedFieldType gets changed to the first value from the select. Any idea?

Comment: What are you setting selectedFieldType to?  In the jsbin I set it in setupController.  Are you setting it there as well?  If you don't set it, it will probably default to the first value in the select.